# Contravariant in scala

Tags: scala

Please help me to understand this code. Why contravariant compile?
It works only if I exactly write type like test_con[Child](new Child)

```
class GrandFather {}
class Father extends GrandFather{}
class Child extends Father{}

def test_cov[T <: Father](man: T) = {}
def test_con[T >: Father](man: T) = {}


test_cov(new GrandFather) // failed, and it's right
test_con(new GrandFather)

test_cov(new Child)
test_con(new Child)  // don't failed. Why?
```

Answer (score 3):

Technically the symbols `<:` and `>:` are not indication of covariance and contravariance. they are called **Upper Bound** and **Lower Bound** respectively.

As to why `test_con(new Child)` compiles:

since class `Child` extends `Father` it means that it **is** a `Father` by every right. Also every type `T` is considered to be both a super type and sub type of itself. that's why passing a `Father` instance to the method 
`def test_con[T >: Father](man: T) = {}` which is asking for a super type of `Father` successfully compiles.

In short: "A `Child` is a `Father` and a `Father` is a super type of `Father`"